# Bootstrap Accordion + x-editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-accordion

I have an [bootstrap accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) which I also applied [x-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) that will only trigger through a link in the dropdown:

[image: this]

I want to remove:

[image: line]

to make it:

[image]

Isn't possible to remove the line below the `x-editable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in a stylesheet that comes after the x-editable stylesheet:

```
.editable-click,
a.editable-click,
a.editable-click:hover {
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your main.js (jquery file that you are using for x-editable).

> .accordion-1 is a class on accordion

```
 $(".accordion-1").attr('style', 'border-bottom: none;');
```